# C# Merge Two DataTables with same amount of columns but different names

Tags: c#, .net, power-automate, rpa, power-automate-desktop

I have this C# Script that I am using in the "Run .NET script" action in Power Automate Desktop (PAD)

```
DT1.Merge(DT2);
FinalTable = DT1.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

These are the script parameters:

| .NET parameter name | Type | Direction | Iput value | Output variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DT1 | Datatable | In | %DataTable% |  |
| DT2 | Datatable | In | %DataTable2% |  |
| FinalTable | Datatable | Out |  | %TemporalTable% |

But, I am having an issue. Both tables have the same amount of columns, but the column names are not the same. So, the tables look like this:

DT1:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 214 | 324233 |
| 233 | 33 |
| 3 | 3 |

DT2:

| Column3 | Column4 |
| --- | --- |
| 3423 | 32454 |
| 55 | 5334 |

And I get this:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 214 | 32433 |  |  |
| 233 | 33 |  |  |
| 3 | 3 |  |  |
|  |  | 3423 | 32454 |
|  |  | 55 | 5334 |

But, what I want for the result is this:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 214 | 32433 |
| 233 | 33 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3423 | 32454 |
| 55 | 5334 |

If I change the script to:

```
DT1.Merge(DT2, false, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
FinalTable = DT1.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

This is what I get:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 214 | 32433 |
| 233 | 33 |
| 3 | 3 |
|  |  |
|  |  |

So I am not getting the values from DT2.

I want to do this and avoid using a for each loop.

So, Can it be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’d start by renaming the columns in the second table to be the same as the first. Then merge the data in. You’d still be looping but only over column names, not data. There may be a better option but if you’re stuck …!

Comment: Yes, that is what I had to do. But I am curious to see if there is a way to accomplish this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> But I am curious to see if there is a way to accomplish this

If you take a look at line 203 of [RecordManager in the .NET source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/RecordManager.cs#L203), you'll see that naming the columns the same (as per the comment) *is* the way to do this if you wish to use the Merge method, which calls upon RecordManager to copy the data:

```
200    int count = table.Columns.Count;
201    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
202      DataColumn dstColumn = table.Columns[i];
203      DataColumn srcColumn = src.Columns[dstColumn.ColumnName];
204      if (null != srcColumn) {
205        object value = srcColumn[record];
206        ICloneable cloneableObject = value as ICloneable;
```

If you seek an alternative that doesn't use Merge(), you'll need to roll your own implementation

- Set one of the tables to have a primary key column, let's call it A
- Loop over the rows of the other table (let's call it B), looking its primary key values up using `A.Rows.Find`
- If you didn't find a row, make a new row
- Run a for loop that copies the data positionally to the found row/new row

Essentially this would be a reinvention of the wheel [Merge](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs) already was; Merge is a very involved and considered block of code that copies everything from old and new (datarows track the original and modified values per column, state and errors)

In summary, I'd say that the best way to perform a positional copy is to just use a for loop to equate the column names before using Merge, so that RecordManager will end up doing a positional copy. It doesn't matter which table you pick on to alter the names of, so long as they're the same, but if one table has the names you want to use in the end, change the names in the other table